# Homotopy equivalence of the two sphere with poles identified

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hello I am having trouble with the following exercise:
We are asked to show that the following spaces are homotopic equivalent:

- The two sphere with north and south pole identified: $\mathbb S^2/\{N ∼ S\}$. (Here N and S represent the north and south pole.
- The two sphere with a interval glueing the north and south pole together: $(\mathbb S^2\cup[0, 1])/\{N ∼ 0, S ∼1\}$.

I need to write down two functions $f,g$ s.t. they are homotopic inverses of each other.

Intuitively it makes sense to me since we can retract the interval to a single point, and the end points of the interval are identified with the north and south pole. And since the interval is contractible it is homotopic equivalent to a single point. But writing explicit functions seems kinda hard.

- Definition: Two spaces $X, Y$ are homotopic equivalent if there exists $f:X\to Y$, and $g:Y\to X$ s.t. $g\circ f ∼ id_X$ and $f \circ g ∼ id_Y$. The composition of the maps is homotopic to the identity.

We were also given a hint to write the two sphere as two copies of discs with the boundary glued together. I don’t really see how this helps with finding the functions $f,g$.

Can someone give a hint on how to define the functions $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$ X= (\mathbb S^2\cup[0, 1])/\{N ∼ 0, S ∼1\},\qquad \qquad Y=\mathbb S^2/\{N ∼ S\}.$$

Then $f\colon X\to Y$ is easy to define.  Following your intuition of retracting the interval to a point, just set $f|_{\mathbb S^2}=1_{\mathbb S^2}$ and $f(t)=N=S$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

Now we need to define $g\colon Y\to X$.  The advantage of regarding $\mathbb S^2$ as a union of a pair of (unit) disks, is that on each disk we can parameterize using polar co-ordinates, with $S$ or $N$ as the origin.

The idea now is simple: Firstly $g\colon N,S\mapsto 0.5\in [0,1]$.  Then for a point $(r,\theta)$, on either disk of $Y$, if $r\leq0.5$ we map $$g\colon (r,\theta)\mapsto 0.5\pm r\in [0,1].$$
Here the sign $\pm$ is determined by which disk $(r,\theta)$ lies on.

Finally if $r\geq0.5$ we map $$g\colon (r,\theta)\mapsto (2r-1,\theta).$$

Now you have to construct the homotopies $g\circ f ∼ id_X$ and $f \circ g ∼ id_Y$.  Let me know if you need help with that.

---

Let's start with the composition $f \circ g$.  This collapses points of radius less than $0.5$ to $N=S$, and applies the function $2r-1$ to radii greater than $0.5$.

We need to construct $H_t\colon Y\to Y$ for $t\in [0,1]$ so that $H_0=1_Y$ and $H_1=f \circ g$.

It makes sense then for $H_t$ to collapse points of radius less than $t/2$ to $N=S$.  Then radii from  $t/2$ to $1$ should get mapped to radii from $0$ to $1$, which we can do linearly:

$$H_t(r,\theta)=H_t\left(\left(\frac {r-\frac t2}{1-\frac t2},\theta\right)\right),\qquad r\geq t/2,$$

and $H_t(r,\theta)=N=S$ if $r\leq t/2$.

Now check these two definitions agree at the boundary $r=t/2$, and that $H_0=1_Y$ and $H_1=f \circ g$.  Check also that points of radius $1$ get mapped to points of radius $1$ for all $t$, as this is needed to ensure continuity where the disks are glued.

Comment: To be honest I find it hard to compare those maps when composed because we have so much going on with identifying the sphere with two discs glued together and $g$ is not very trivial. Could u show me how to construct the homotopies? I never saw any non trivial examples of spaces being homotopic equivalent. Its like I have no tools in my bag, maybe seeing more examples will give me a better understanding. Thanks!

Comment: OK I will do one to start with.  Before I do that - have you checked that the maps I defined are continuous e.g. the local definitions agree at the boundaries?

Comment: I think f is continuous due to the pasting lemma. And g looks well defined on the boundary of either disk and is continuous aswel!

Comment: Yes, but make sure you have checked  that the definitions agree at the boundary $r=0.5$ and that $g(N)=g(S)$.

Comment: Yes I just wrote it out! Im still struggling to make sense that the maps composed are homotopic to the identity.

Comment: I have done one of them.  The trick is usually just to figure out what you want to go where and then extend linearly.  You can visualize it by picturing water flowing to the $N=S$ point, but staying still where the disks meet.